# What are all the hidden messages found in searchable containers?

Tags: red-dead-redemption-2

Throughout the world, I've found a couple of messages carved into the bottom of dresser/nightstand drawers.  For example, this one states:

> You flourish before you die

[image: drawer message]

What are all of the hidden messages in the searchable containers around the world? Is there any meaning to them or are they purely for atmosphere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're [cheats](https://reddead.fandom.com/wiki/Cheats_in_Redemption_2) for the game. You can find the cheats all over the world or in newspapers.

Some cheats can be activated without finding them in the map, other not (you need certain newspapers on your inventory which some are only available further in the story)

That cheat in specific:

> “You flourish before you die” - Refills all bars for health, stamina, and dead eye

Using cheats in the game will deactivate achievements and save games.